# Elasticsearchで複数のindexから値を取得するQuery

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearchで１つのQueryで複数のindexや複数のtypeの情報を一気に抽出する方法はありますか？
SQLで書くと下記のようなことを実現したいのですが、お分かりになる方はいらっしゃいますか？

```sql
SELECT (case
 when cafe.name like "%コメダ%" then cafe.name
 when restaurant.name like "%コメダ%" then restaurant.name
 ELSE  null END
) shopname
FROM cafe,restaurant
GROUP BY shopname;
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-index.html

によれば、 restAPI においては、 index が入るところに、カンマ区切りで複数インデックスを与えてやれば、問題なく動作しそうです。